# I have been writing PHP without "classes" for years... what am I missing?

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

For the life of me, I can't seem to wrap my head around "classes" in PHP.

I have managed to write large, scalable, and popular websites without them.

What am I missing? (And how do I learn?)

Comment: oops. You are missing OOP

Comment: try to use frameworks (zend,code igniter, ect.) this way you would learn more about classes, MVC and more

Comment: *Nothing*. Procedural programming is a very valid way to write programs, and if it works for you, that's awesome, keep at it. Using objects instead is a different way of thinking and working, and if you want to learn, be prepared to invest some time.

Comment: I found the early parts of this book explain the benefits fairly well: http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-5-Objects-Patterns-Practice/dp/1590593804/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1329817307&sr=8-1

Comment: if you dont need "inheritance" or  "concurrency" (like 99% of projects dont) you dont need oop and IF you do then use C++ or Python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classes will help with code re-use and potentially a very structured application.

Procedural programming can be a lot faster in both development time and execution speed.

OO programming is the more mainstream way but not always the best way. Theres a book called  PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice which is a very good read, it covers the basics of classes,  why and how to use, abstraction and common design patterns such as MVC. It also covers unit testing and other very good practices for php developers

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting it's not always the best way.

Answer (score 9):

The point of classes (object oriented programming) is that it bundles data together with the code that operates on it. If done well, this leads to less tightly coupled and thus more maintainable code.

In practice it means fewer global variables (whether used directly or accessed through static factory methods) and lesss passing around of data (i.e. smaller method signatures).

For a concrete example, look at the [Mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php): each function has a procedural and an OOP version, and the procedural version nearly always needs to have an extra "link" parameter to give it context, wheras the OOP version gets that context from the current object.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody answered was right you are missing a lot because let's say you have a photo gallery website
instead of writing functions and in the end you end with a lot of them

OOP would be useful in:

1. Code organization and maintainability
2. Adds clarity, and reduce complexity
3. Emphasizes data over procedures
4. Code modularity
5. Code re-usability (Believe me you will need that a lot)
6. Well-suited for databases

I wasn't using OOP before but i started and to be honest not very long time ago, and found it very useful in those points specially in the re-usability of the code

Let's say i have a photo gallery website
i will create a class for users and this class will do CRUD on all of the users table
and a class for the photos to do the CRUD on all of the photographs table

I could also make a class to do all the CRUD for me without specifying on what table 
and then use the inheritance to extend all the CRUD in my users class and my photograph class

the point in that is i could only write the CRUD methods once
and then re-use it in all of my other classes

I hope i would have answered your question

Answer (score 3):

IMO, If you do not wish to seperate your htmls & php code; you better not use classes.

You'll need them in a framework environment (not necessarily), and you'll need them if you want to objectify your datas, handle them like that.

but if you're fine without it, then you're just fine :)

When it comes to handle a very complex system, with a lot of different data structures, more than one team members, etc. You and your code need to be organized very well, and you'll need classes.

Answer (score 2):

Good question! You got my upvote!

Straight to the point:
**You're missing a whole world**!

There are many metaphors to describe it but there's nothing better than practice - you obviously know it after "years" of programming!

**Decide on a small project and write it OOP style**. Then you'll get the idea.

Take this tip as well: Name your classes as their file names (ex. "MyClass" -> "MyClass.php"). Easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing testability: I guess your functions call other functions, which in turn might call another function, right? So you will have trouble testing an isolated function. With OOP you assemble "heaps" of objects and can interchange each object with a "fake" one (called mock or stub) for a test. This way, you can test each functionality in isolation. Think of being able to test you output code without needing a database. Think of testing your controller code (the code which processes the request parameters and decides what action to take) without needing a web server.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. It makes the assumption that written functions will be calling other functions. The argument for mocks or stubs applies as much to the inputs of functions as it does methods in a class. In fact, a procedural style of coding is closer to a functional programming style where it is less of a step to write pure functions which are infitely more testable.